# Create a keyword from a number

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, hoplon

## tl;dr

How can I derive a keyword from a number in ClojureScript:

```clj
(keyword 22)
;;=> :22 but in fact returns nil.
```

## Background

In my ClojureScript/Hoplon application I make HTTP requests via [cljs-http](https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http). Parts of the response I receive look like this:

```clj
{:companies
  {:22 {:description ... } ; A company.
   :64 {:description ... }
   ...                    }
{:offers
  [{:description ... } ; An offer.
   {:description ... }
   ...                ]
```

Each offer within the vector behind `:offers` has a `:companyId` which represents a key in `:companies`. As soon as I receive the response, I `reset!` a [cell](https://github.com/hoplon/javelin) (similar to an atom) `query`.

Now, I'd like to iterate over each offer and call a function `offer-tpl` that creates the corresponding HTML. In order to do so, `offer-tpl` needs the offer itself as well as the related company:

```clj
(for [offer (:offers @query)]
  (offer-tpl offer (get-in @query [:companies (keyword (:companyId offer))]))))))
```

Despite the fact that this surely can be done more elegant (suggestions very appreciated), the `get-in` doesn't work. `(:companyId offer)` returns a number (e.g. `22`) but `(keyword (:companyId offer))` returns `nil`. Calling `(keyword (str (:companyId offer)))` does the trick, but aren't there any other ways to do this?

Comment: Is there the special reason for indexing companies with keywords, not numbers? `{:companies {22 {:description ...} 23 {:description ...}}}` ? Where do you get this response from? can you change the format there?

Comment: @leetwinski That's just how the API responses, the JSON looks like this: `"companies": { "22": { ... } }`. AFAIK cljs-http uses [transit-cljs](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-cljs) to transform the response into native ClojureScript data structures.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`(keyword "22")` or `(keyword (str 22))` returns `:22`

The reason you are getting `:22` is likely because of the `keywordize-keys` option of a JSON translation. For example:

cljs-http defaults to keywordize-keys for jsonp:
https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http/blob/1fb899d3f9c5728521786432b5f6c36d1d7a1452/src/cljs_http/core.cljs#L115
But you can (and should) in this case pass in a flag to disable keywordization.

Not all keys in JSON are appropriate for Clojure keywordization. For example spaces in a JSON key are valid, but not in Clojure.

Please be aware that numeric keywords are probably incorrect.
https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keyword#example-542692cec026201cdc326d70
It seems like that caveat has been removed from the current Clojure website, so perhaps that means something but I'm not sure what.

http://clojure.org/reference/reader Currently states that

> Keywords - Keywords are like symbols, except: They can and must begin
>   with a colon, e.g. :fred. They cannot contain '.' or name classes.
>   Like symbols, they can contain a namespace, :person/name A keyword
>   that begins with two colons is resolved in the current namespace: In
>   the user namespace, ::rect is read as :user/rect

and that

> Symbols begin with a non-numeric character and can contain
>   alphanumeric.

This definition of a keyword excludes `:22` and `:with spaces`

The keyword function returns a result for invalid input, but this is not an endorsement, it is simply because checking for incorrect input would be a performance overhead in a core part of Clojure.

In short, not all JSON keys translate to keywords, so you should avoid `keywordize-keys` unless you know the keyspace and/or doing so provides some conveniences.

Comment: Spaces are valid for Clojure keywords, they're just not common. `(keyword "with spaces")` returns `:with spaces`.

Comment: @HoagyCarmichael you can not "test for correctness" with `(keyword "...")`, since `keyword` does not behave correctly according to the specs. `keyword` will work with (close to) everything and that's the reason OP is in this mess.